# Socket stops communicating

Tags: python, sockets, networking, raspberry-pi

I'm running python 2.7 code on a Raspberry Pi that receives serial data from an Arduino, processes it, and sends it to a Windows box over a wifi link. The Pi is wired to a Linksys router running in client bridge mode and that router connects over wifi to another Linksys router to which the Windows box is wired. The code in the Pi runs fine for some (apparently) random interval, and then the Pi becomes unreachable from the Windows box.

I'm running PUTTY on the the Windows machine to connect to the Pi and when the fail occurs I get a message saying there's been a network error and the Pi is not reachable. Pinging the Pi from the Windows machine works fine until the error, at which time it produces "Reply from 192.168.0.129: Destination host unreachable." The client bridge router to which the Pi is connected remains reachable.

I've got the networking code on the Pi wrapped in an exception handler, and when it fails it shows the following:

> Ethernet problem:
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "garage.py", line 108, in module
>       s.connect((host, port))
>     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 224, in meth
>     return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
>   error: [Errno 113] No route to host
>   None

The relevant python code looks like:

```
import socket
import traceback
host = '192.168.0.129'  
port = 31415
```

in the setup, and after serial data has been processed:

```
try:
    bline = strline.encode('utf-8')
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect((host, port))
    s.send(bline)
    s.close()
except:
    print "Ethernet problem: "
    print traceback.print_exc()
```

Where strline contains the processed data. As I said, this runs fine for a few hours more or less before failing. Any ideas?

EDIT: When PUTTY fails its error message is "Network Error: Software caused connection abort."

EDIT: When the interface shuts down I see this in dmesg:

> [Wed Nov  6 16:53:15 2013] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0: eth0: link down
>   [Wed Nov  6 16:53:17 2013] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0: eth0: link up, 100Mbps, full-duplex, lpa 0x45E1

at about 4 hours after the Pi boots up. This follows sys.exit() on the exception.

Comment: This seems to be a problem with your wireless link. What wireless network adapter are you using on the pi. Please check `dmesg` if you see any errors there. My guess is that you will see the wireless adapter trying to re-associate with the router.

Comment: The Pi is not wireless, it is direct-connected to the Linksys that is configured as a client bridge.

Comment: @hogliux I did check dmesg and found that the eth0 link went down after about 4 hours and then came back up two seconds later. I couldn't see how to put the lines in this comment so they are in an edit to the main question. So the question looks like it's Why is my code shutting down the eth0 interface?

Comment: How do you run the dhcp client on the pi? Does it automatically rerun dhcpcd or dhclient when the link comes back up? If not, check out netplugd. It's very light-weight and easy to configure.

Comment: @hogliux I've got the Pi configured with a static IP address.